# RESTAPI that will get the list of mailing lists from MailChimp based on the API key in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

As a user i want to load the list of my mailing lists from MailChimp in my application using RESTFUL API in laravel 5.5, and i am not finding any suitable answer if anyone have suitable link or any idea please let me know.

Your help will be appreciated !

Comment: I think you can use jwt token for authentication and api/ prefix routes. if you explain more i can better help you

Answer (score 1):

Complete API documentation is given [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/)
You want to authenticate MailChimp first.
All the request formats are given at the API doc. Please go through the link.